# Understanding pattern matching with cons operator

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, cons

In "Programming F#" I came across a pattern-matching like this one (I simplified a bit):

```
let rec len list = 
  match list with
  | [] -> 0
  | [_] -> 1
  | head :: tail -> 1 + len tail;;
```

Practically, I understand that the last match recognizes the head and tail of the list. Conceptually, I don't get why it works. As far as I understand, :: is the cons operator, which appends a value in head position of a list, but it doesn't look to me like it is being used as an operator here. Should I understand this as a "special syntax" for lists, where :: is interpreted as an operator or a "match pattern" depending on context? Or can the same idea be extended for types other than lists, with other operators?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to Brian's answer, there are a few points that are worth noting. The `h::t` syntax can be used both as an operator *and* as a pattern:

```
let l = 1::2::[]                    // As an operator
match l with x::xs -> 1 | [] -> 0   // As a pattern
```

This means that it is a bit special construct, because other operators (for example `+`) cannot be used as patterns (for decomposing the result back to the arguments of the operator) - obviously, for `+`, this would be ambiguous.

Also, the pattern `[_]` is interesting, because it is an example of nested pattern. It composes:

- `_` - Underscore pattern, which matches any value and doesn't bind any symbols
- `[ <pattern> ]` - Single-element list pattern, which matches a lists with single elements and matches the element of the list with the nested `<pattern>`.

You could also write `match 1::[] with | [x] -> x` which would return the value of the single element (in this case 1).

Comment: Thank you, your point about :: being a special construct is exactly what I was unclear about. I experimented trying to use other operators in pattern-matching the "same" way, but it didn't make much sense and I got nowhere, which is what got me wondering about cons.

Comment: Note that the same is true for Tuples - you can use the (,) pattern to build and to match/unpack tuples, and for other types too (Some()/None) etc.

Comment: Here is a list of [all supported pattern types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching) with examples.

Answer (score 14):

It is special syntax for lists.  You can think of the `list` type as a discriminated union thusly:

```
type list<'T> =         // '
    | Nil
    | Cons of 'T * list<'T>
```

except that there's special syntax that makes `Nil` be `[]` and `Cons(h,t)` be `h::t`.  Then it's just normal pattern matching on a discriminated union.  Does that help?

(Possibly see also [this blog entry](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!172.entry).)

Answer (score 5):

It is used as a formatter or formally `pattern`, `list' is matched to the three patterns:

[] means the list is empty

[_] means the list has one element, since you don't care about what the element is, so simply put _ there, you can also use [a].

head::tail means that the list does have two parts: a head and a tail.

You can view F# pattern matching as a powerful if then else structure.